# Build javamail-android

Tags: java, android, maven, glassfish, jakarta-mail

Im trying to build the library http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/ myself. However there are files missing. For example bootstrap/ant-common.xml Did anyone manage to build it? Thanks!

```
BUILD FAILED
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/Downloads/javamail-android-read-     only/bootstrap/ant-common.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:70)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:161)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:651)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1313)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1250)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEntityReference(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1906)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3033)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:307)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:178)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(ProjectHelper.java:82)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:793)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a brilliant project, it is also an Android library project. Ready to use out of the box:

https://github.com/lucabelluccini/javamail_android

I could NOT compile:

http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/

All files are not checked in and author is unwilling to help.

Comment: I see that the github project you provided, much like the google code project, has been abandoned.  Do you know of any updated versions?